# Twitter share button shows blank page. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to share my twitter button on the blog posts. It is working fine in 18 posts out of 20. Only 2 posts have problems. The blank window appears on clicking the button with no text, url and via etc...

**The URLS**

1. [National Tour Announced For Disney’s The Little Mermaid](http://www.excite.com/events/blog/national-tour-announced-disneys-little-mermaid/)
2. [MLB Venues – How A Team’s Form Is Effecting Ticket Prices At Their Homes](http://www.excite.com/events/blog/mlb-venues-teams-form-effecting-ticket-prices-homes/)

**Is my code good or what happened here ? Please assist me.**

```css
.tweet{ margin:0px auto; width:200px; text-align:center;}
.tweet a{ display:inline-block; line-height:50px; color:#f00; text-decoration:none; background:#ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:0px 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="tweet">
<a title="Twitter" href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?share=" onclick="tweetShare=window.open(this.href+escape(window.location)+'&text='+escape(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML)+'&url='+location.href+'&via=ExciteEventstix','tweetShare','toolbar=no,status=no,width=640,height=400,scrollbars=no'); return false;"
target="_blank">Twitter</a></div>
```

Comment: Check the source code shows for the two posts that are empty. Should give you an idea of what's breaking.

Comment: check your browser `console`. There  should be some error logged!

Comment: It would be nice if you could tell what urls and titles those two posts have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Chrome Developer console you will find out twitter server returned a 400 error. That was because you didn't encode the url (especially, the `title` parameter) correctly.

Note the `%u2019` character after the `Disney`. Its an encoded unicode character. Actually twitter expects you encode it as UTF-8.

```
text=National%20Tour%20Announced%20for%20Disney%u2019s%20The%20Little%20Mermaid
```

The solution is to use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `escape()`. This code should work fine:

```
<div class="tweet">
<a title="Twitter" href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?share=" onclick="tweetShare=window.open(this.href+encodeURIComponent(window.location)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML)+'&url='+location.href+'&via=ExciteEventstix','tweetShare','toolbar=no,status=no,width=640,height=400,scrollbars=no'); return false;"
target="_blank">Twitter</a></div>
```

Anyway `escape()` is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) so please try `encodeURIComponent` instead.

BTW

1. There's no `share` parameter supported in [tweet button documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button). `url` is enough.
2. `document.title` works as perfect as the long version `document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML`.
3. Don't create an extra global variable `tweetShare`, if not used.

So this may be simplified as:

```
<div class="tweet">
<a title="Twitter" href="javascript:window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'&via=ExciteEventstix','tweetShare','toolbar=no,status=no,width=640,height=400,scrollbars=no')">Twitter</a></div>
```